# parsing django test results

Tags: django, parsing, testing

I recently wrote some tests for one of my django Projects. What I now want to do is to call the test command from a script.

I am looking to parse the test results and save them. Is that at all possible for django testing framework?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a standard test output format, such as JUnit XML, for which there are already [libraries](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jux). Right now, I'm using django-jenkins, which provides a nice output that I can view in our CI tool.

If you'd like to roll your own solution, I'd reccomend coding your own Test Runner, and customizing the [suite_result](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.simple.DjangoTestSuiteRunner.suite_result) method.

Comment: I ended up writing my own test runner.